# How to get the title of HTML page with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, title

How can I get the title of an HTML page with JavaScript?

Comment: Note that there's a slight difference between using `document.title` and accessing the `title` element directly, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65241128/2604492).

Answer (score 439, accepted):

Use `document.title`:

```js
console.log(document.title)
```

```html
<title>Title test</title>
```

[MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title)

Comment: HTML5 version ;) `<script>if (typeof(console.log) === "function") {alert(document.title);}</script>`

Comment: @OregonTrail wut?, if `console.log`, then `alert` anyway?

Comment: What's the point of including `<script>` tag in answer if question is about JavaScript? Also, [`type` attribute is completely unnecessary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195427/is-the-type-attribute-necessary-for-script-tags) and IMHO [`console.log()` is much better for debugging than `alert()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203473/why-is-console-log-considered-better-than-alert).

Comment: This answer says that `document.title` returns the HTML title element, but as the code snippet shows, it does not do that. It returns the text that is inside the HTML title element. That's a pretty big difference.

Answer (score 18):

Put in the URL bar and then click enter:

```
javascript:alert(document.title);
```

You can select and copy the text from the alert depending on the website and the web browser you are using.

Answer (score 13):

Can use `getElementsByTagName`

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0];

alert(x.innerHTML)

// or

alert(x.textContent)

// or

document.querySelector('title')
```

Edits as suggested by [Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2604492/paul)

Comment: This answer is great if your parsing an HTML doc

Comment: 1. Use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` - the title is pure text. 2. Use `querySelector("title")` instead of `getElementsByTagName("title")[0]` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54952474/2604492).

Answer (score 0):

this makes the h1 element the page title. this shows how capable can be javascript for small and big projects.

```js
document.getElementById("text").innerText = document.title;
```

```html
<title>hello world</title>
<h1 id="text"></h1>
```