# Calculate Opacity Value on Size

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to calculate opacity inversely based on the size of an object. Basically the bigger it is, the more transparent it will be.

The object size is calculated like so:

```
var baseSize = 60;
var sVariance = 4;
var outputA = [];

function blah() {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        this.newSize = Math.ceil(baseSize - (Math.random() * sVariance));
        outputA[i] = this.newSize;
    }
    document.writeln("Size = "+outputA);
}

blah();​
```

...I would like to be able to calculate the opacity strength between the range of sizes. For example, if the 5 sizes generated were:  60,59,58,57,59  I would like the corresponding opacity values to be as such: .25,.5,.75,1,.5

I apologize if something like this has already been covered, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the function I would use. You can see the logic to convert the value in the function. Also here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ve2A3/2/).

Note that the `$.map` function is a jQuery function which is very convenient to translate array items. If you're not using jQuery, you can replace it with a for loop.

```js
function getOpacityArray (sizeArray, max, range) {
    return $.map(sizeArray, function (n, i) {
        return (max - n) / range;
    });
}
```

So in your example you can get the opacity array after you calculate the size array, something like this:

```js
var baseSize  = 60, 
    sVariance = 4,
    outputA   = [], 
    opacityA  = [];

function blah() {
   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      this.newSize = Math.ceil(baseSize - (Math.random() * sVariance));
      outputA[i] = this.newSize;
   }
   document.writeln("Size = "+outputA);
   opacityA = getOpacityArray(outputA, baseSize, sVariance);
}

blah();
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to normalize the data so that the maximum is at 1 and the minimum is some fraction. It would help to define what you want that fraction to be (eg. always 0.25, 1 / # of values). How you normalize the data depends on that choice.

Consider doing things like subtracting everything by the lowest value in the list, or dividing everything by the greatest value, or both.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSizes(baseSize, sVariance) {
    var sizes = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        sizes[i] = Math.ceil(baseSize - (Math.random() * sVariance));
    }
    return sizes;
}

function calculateOpacityValues(baseSize, sVariance) {
    var min = 0.25, max = 1,
        step = 0.75 / sVariance, i,
        opacityValues = {};
    for (i = 0; i <= sVariance; i++) {
        opacityValues[baseSize - i] = min + step * i;
    }
    return opacityValues;
}

function getOpacities(sizes, opacityValues) {
    // create a map of opacities
    // and your expected values
    var opacities = [];
    sizes.forEach(function(value, index) {
        opacities[index] = opacityValues[value];
    });
    return opacities;
}

var baseSize = 60, sVariance = 3, 
    sizes = getSizes(baseSize, sVariance);
console.log(sizes);
// use the map to get the opacity
console.log(getOpacities(sizes, calculateOpacityValues(baseSize, sVariance)));​
```

​
You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xMkVS/2/). It uses the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) construct which is not supported in older browsers, but if you need to, you'll be able to switch it to a normal for loop. I've also refactored your code a bit by moving all the generation logic in the `getSizes` method and all the opacity calculation in the `getOpacities` method.

On a sidenote, you should use `console.log` for debugging (this logs in FireBug's console on FireFox, in the Chrome WebInspector window or in the IE development console). This is a lot better than `document.write` ([this is true](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8203484/182629) for this case also, even if we're not talking about `alert` here).

### Edit

<s>You didn't mention if you want the `baseSize` and the `variance` to be variable. In that case, you should add a method to generate the opacity value map based on your logic.</s>
I've added the logic you requested in the sample and I've updated the code.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify but the baseSize and sVariance are variables set by the user.