# getting values from a modal using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

-----------**SOLVED**-----------

thanks for taking the time to help me. i managed to  make it work now. i think the problem was my negligence. i have to add the `getVal` on my modal like so `id="modal_"getVal`. it was calling the wrong modal, thats why the input box returns empty. Im very sorry for this and I appreciate the help people do. thank you

---

i have a simple modal which contains a textbox and button.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="textb" val_A="1">
<button type="button" id="but"> submit </button>
```

i want to get the textbox `.val()` and the attributes `val_A`  upon button click

```
$(document).on('click','#but', function() {
name = $('#textb').attr('value');
val_A = $('#textb').attr('val_A');

alert(name + "-" + val_A);

});
```

but Im getting **undefined** result for the `name`.

ive also tried `$('#textb').val();` and it didn't worked.

please note that i want the values from a textbox inside a modal, and not sure if theres a different approach of getting values considering modal behaviour.

----------**[update]**-----------

When this button is clicked, modal will appear

```
<button type="button" class="btn" val="1"> show modal </button>
```

The button has a specific value with it, `val=1` which then activates a specific modal. thus, `$(#modal_+getVal)`.

```
$(document).on('click','.btn', function () {
getVal = $(this).attr('val');
$('#modal_+getVal').modal({show:true})
});
```

Which then brings me to my question above. after the modal appears, i want to get the value of the textbox upon clicking yet, another button inside the modal.

but all it shows is **undefined**

Comment: Can you show us your markup and the rest of your JS. Do you have any other element with the id `textb` anywhere else on your page?

Comment: the value attribute does not get updated in real time the same way the value property does

Comment: are you getting val_A  correctly?

Comment: You are saying that form is in modal dialog. initial state form fields will be in hidden mode. so you have to get the fields from the form after showing the form in callback method. or you have to use :hidden selector to get the form field value. are you using jquery dialog or any other plugin? let me know . if you are using jquery dialog you can have dialog show callback $( ".selector" ).dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) { here get the field values }
});

Comment: @Jagadeesh thanks for your inputs. im using bootstrap modal and not jquery dialog.

Comment: If my answer is helped you to find the problem make sure you mark it as correct answer so it may help to other people

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any difference between a modal and any other div, concerning your problem. If the textarea (your textbox is a textarea, isn't it?) isn't in another frame or iframe, you can find the modal with 'normal' jQuery selector usage. That being said, here are some possible solutions:

If your textbox is a textarea, try this:

```
var textbox_value = $('#textb').val();
```

If all of that doesn't work, try to figure out if you are selecting the correct element! What does `console.log($('#textbox'))` print?

**Edit:**

Oh, and, yes. You might want to try this:

```
<div id="foo" data-valA="test"></div>

<script>
    $('#foo').data('valA');
</script>
```

**Edit 2:**

I cannot link this one often enough: [Why is console.log() considered better than alert()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203473/why-is-console-log-considered-better-than-alert)

Comment: `data()` won't work without `data-` prefix in the markup for the attribute and an `input` has no `text()`

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote data-valA. And I know that an input has no text, that's what it's all about. Although I have to admit, I didn't see the input there and assumed his textbox might be any kind of element. (Whoops!) Edit: Deleted it, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: i have used `console.log()` and it prints nothing. just blank. values inputted from textbox doesnt print.

Comment: But it does find the textbox itself?

Comment: hi, sorry. can you enlighten me what you mean 'finds the textbox itself' ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought that was clear. You can write both console.log($('#textb')) and console.log($('#textb').val()) - version a returns the textbox and version b should return the textbox value. Edit: http://s14.directupload.net/images/140709/ravdavei.png (the box exists vs. the box doesn't exist)

Comment: http://imgur.com/uMY8t2l this shows up in my console. `console.log($('#textb'))` prints the the textbox, and `console.log($('#textb').val())` shows blank :(

Comment: Looks like #textb cannot be found (as a test, try $(document).click(function(){ console.log($('#nonExistentId')); }); ). Okay, maybe that's caused by the Bootstrap error thrown. Where does this come from? Did you check your devtools if the element actually exists?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
    var modelNumber = $(this).val()
    console.log('model number',modelNumber);
    $('#modal_'+modelNumber).modal({show:true})
    $('#modal_'+modelNumber).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
      console.log('modal dialog shown, get the form values')
      // try to get input values here
   }) });
```

And change your input type button attribute "val" to "value".