# ajax serializearray not outputting any value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form HTML as follow:

```
<div id="error_message"></div>

<form action="daterequest.php"  id="daterequest_form" method="post">

            <select name="option1">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>

            <input type="text" name="option2" >

    </form>
```

and I have JS script like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button_submit_form').on('click', function () {
  var data = $('#daterequest_form').serializeArray();   
  alert(data);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'daterequest.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data, 
        success: function(response) 
            {

                if (response == 'empty') { 
                  $('#error_message').text('ERROR MESSAFGE') } 
                else    {
                    $('#error_message').html(response);
                    $('#daterequest_form').fadeOut('400');
                }; 
            }
    });     
    e.preventDefault();
});


});
```

my `alert(data);`  only gives me `[object Object], [object Object]`.

I can't get the data to show in my alert.. I should see `[option1 Value], [option2 inputvalue]`

Also, once I figure out how to get the data in the alert, how to I retrieve it in PHP?   `$_POST['what goes here'];` ?

Comment: Don't use `alert()` for debugging as it coerces values to strings - hence the `[object Object], [object Object]`. Use `console.log()` instead. From what you describe it sounds like `serializeArray()` is working correctly. I would say that `serialize()` sounds more suited to your needs though.

Comment: try alert(data['option1']); or alert(data.option1); instead of alert(data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue here - the problem is because you're using `alert()` to debug. This means that the variable being displayed is coerced to a string, hence the array of objects is turned in to `'[object Object], [object Object]'`. Instead use `console.log()` to debug your code.

Also, from what you're trying to do I would suggest that using the `serialize()` method is more suited to your needs, and you should hook to the `submit` event of the `form` so that people using the keyboard also fire the event when the submit the form by pressing the Enter key. Try this:

```
$('#daterequest_form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();   
    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'daterequest.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data, 
        success: function(response) {
            if (response == 'empty') { 
                $('#error_message').text('ERROR MESSAFGE') 
            } else {
                $('#error_message').html(response);
                $('#daterequest_form').fadeOut('400');
            }; 
        }
    });     
});
```

Then in your PHP you can retrieve the passed data by using `$_POST` and specifying the `name` of the form value:

```
var option1 = $_POST['option1'];
var option2 = $_POST['option2'];
```

Answer (score 1):

`alert` will not give you the details of the object use `console.log()` instead :

```
console.log(data);
```

Take a look to [Why is console.log() considered better than alert()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203473/why-is-console-log-considered-better-than-alert).

Hope this helps.