# Unable to retrieve element by id from an HTML string

Tags: jquery

I have a PHP that returns an HTML snippet as string in the following format:

```
echo '<tr><td>blah</td><td>more blah</td></tr><tr><td>blah</td><td>more blah</td></tr><tr><td>blah</td><td>more blah</td></tr><span id="morerows">1</span>';
```

Now at the client, I am using JQuery (2.1.4) to extract the text of `#morerows` (in this example, 1) into a local `var ifmore` and then remove that `<span>` from the original HTML before further processing. Following is what I am trying for testing purposes:

```
var hr = createXMLHTTPRequestObject();
...
var return_data = hr.responseText;
var rdasHTML = $(return_data);
var ifmore = $('span#morerows', rdasHTML);
alert(ifmore.text());
```

But it only alerts blank. The HTTP request is processing fine because `alert(return_data);` shows the value expected. Only the extraction of the `<span>` element is somehow not working. Is there something I am missing out?

Comment: You can return only `#morerows` value (1 in your code) from server and use it, without any jquery selector.

Comment: [Use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` for debugging.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203473/why-is-console-log-considered-better-than-alert)

Comment: What do you mean I can only return `#morerows` value from the server? Why shouldn't one be able to just extract an element with a specific ID from a returned HTML string? I am returning `#morerows` as a separate `span` tag within the string because there's other stuff (the `<td>`'s) I need as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap your code in a `div`, because now jQuery is parsing only the first tag and ignoring the rest. Your code should be:

```
echo '<div><tr><td>blah</td><td>more blah</td></tr><tr><td>blah</td><td>more blah</td></tr><tr><td>blah</td><td>more blah</td></tr><span id="morerows">1</span></div>';
```

To explain further:

```
console.log($("<tr><td>test</td></tr><span>test</span>")[0].outerHTML);
```

gives:

```
"<tr><td>test</td></tr>"
```