# jquery.validate showErrors() triggered multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate, jquery-forms-plugin

In my test program, I use jquery.validate plugin to check user input fields as so:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-form-3.51.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-validation-1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="form-profile" method="post">
    <input name="Age" type="text" />
    <input name="Gender" type="text" />
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

<script>
$(function() {
    setValidateRules();
});

function setValidateRules() {
    $("#form-profile").validate({
        rules: {
            Age: "required",
            Gender: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            Age: "Please fill in age",
            Gender: "Please fill in gender",
        },
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(errorMap));
        }
    });
}

$("#form-profile").ajaxForm({
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {
        return $("#form-profile").valid();
    },
    error: function(result) {
        // todo
    },
    success: function(result) {
        // todo
    }
});
</script>
```

Now my problem is, when I run the page via browser, after clicking submit button, the page keeps popping up alert box recursively, which makes me believe that showErrors() handler is called multiple (many many) times.

Is there a way to solve this problem ?

> updated jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1nnqf7qs/

Comment: Just as general advice, try using `console.log("stuff")` rather than alert with debugging, then keeping your console open to view them (f12 on windows). Makes it much easier to see whats going on, as console logs dont get in your way like alerts do - especially if there are a lot of em

Comment: Where is your submit event in jquery ?

Comment: I've tried to use console.log, and it seem that console.log() runs 3 times on every call (page load). That's also a strange result, I don't know why alert() is triggered recursively and log only triggered 3 times @Carl

Comment: @Loading.. $("#form-profile").ajaxForm(...) is the submit handler, i use ajaxForm plugin

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle ?

Comment: Can you take your ajaxForm code inside document.ready event.

Comment: @Loading.. jsfiddle added, please check my update

Comment: [Your jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nnqf7qs/) does not contain the jQuery Library or the jQuery Validate plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> jquery.validate `showErrors()` triggered multiple times?

It's really not.  Using `console.log()` confirms that each triggering event only fires `showErrors()` **one** time.  For your demo, default triggering events are `click` of submit button, and `focusout` and `keyup` of each text `input`.<sup>1</sup>

> Now my problem is, when I run the page via browser, after clicking submit button, the page keeps popping up alert box recursively, which makes me believe that `showErrors()` handler is called multiple (many many) times.

It has to do with how/when ***`alert()` halts all JavaScript execution until it's dismissed***, and how/when certain browsers handle the `alert()`. *(I've seen Safari get stuck in an infinite loop of alerts where a `console.log()` in its place would have fired one time.)*

This can be proven by simply replacing your `alert()` with a `console.log()` and you can see `showErrors` **is really only fired ONE time per each triggering event**.<sup>2</sup>

DEMO: [jsfiddle.net/1nnqf7qs/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/1nnqf7qs/1/)

<sup>1</sup>**EDIT**:  When the `alert()` is clicked, the field immediately loses focus (`focusout` event fires), which triggers another `alert()` that will appear as soon as the first `alert()` dismisses.  Infinite loop.  When using `console.log()`, the field never loses focus so no additional notifications are triggered.

<sup>2</sup>**EDIT**:  After initial form validation (after "lazy" turns into "eager" validation), when you click the button, you are then triggering TWO events... `focusout` and `click` and the `showErrors` function responds accordingly by firing twice (once per each of these two different events).

> Is there a way to solve this problem ?

**Do not** use an `alert()` for development and troubleshooting, use `console.log()` instead.

See:  [`console.log()` versus `alert()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8203473/594235)

Otherwise, I see no problem with how the `showErrors` function is being fired.

---

You also need to put your Ajax ***INSIDE*** the `submitHandler` function of the `.validate()` method.  [As per docs, this is where it belongs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler).

```
$("#form-profile").validate({
    rules: {
        Age: "required",
        Gender: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        Age: "Please fill in age",
        Gender: "Please fill in gender",
    },
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(errorMap));
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(form).ajaxForm({
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {
                // form is ALREADY valid when submitHandler fires
                // return $("#form-profile").valid(); // <- do NOT need this here
            }, ....
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Then once inside the `submitHandler`, you no longer need to check if the form is valid, because the `submitHandler` only fires when the form is valid.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. The only problem is that when I run test with console.log(), it actually logs 2 times in chrome inspect window:  `demo.html:76 {"Age":"Please fill in age"}`, `demo.html:76 {"Age":"Please fill in age","Gender":"Please fill in gender"}`, it seems that showError() handler will be triggered by every single error in page

Comment: @ineztia, I am only seeing `showErrors()` triggered once for each `keyup`, once for each `focusout`, and once when I click the button.  Otherwise, how else would you get an immediate and accurate accounting of errors?  So  I don't understand why this is a problem for you.

Comment: @ineztia, of course it's triggered for every single error on the page... otherwise, it would continue to show errors after the user fixes them or not show errors at all.

Comment: So how does disabling the `onfocuout` triggering event solve anything?  What was the real problem with how this works in the first place?

Comment: @Sparky In my test, after submit, the console.log() may fire 2 times as there're 2 error fields (Age and Gender) in page. Chrome inspect window will only show the first log explicitly and collapse other log rows by default, when you click on the log, it will expand the hidden log rows. I don't know if you mean firing 2 times is correct for the validation mechanism.

Comment: @ineztia, again, what is the real problem here... you don't really want to use `alert()` boxes in production, do you?  As far as `showErrors` firing for each field... of course that's correct as how else do you expect the function to correctly report errors as they dynamically toggle.  If you're merely looking for an explanation, see my last edit as I've fully provided that.

Comment: @ineztia, also don't forget that after initial form validation (after "lazy" turns into "eager"), when you click the submit, you are triggering TWO events... `focusout` and `click`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use

```
onfocusout: false
```

Alert always fire because focus out always fire for alert.

```
function setValidateRules() {
    $("#form-profile").validate({
        onfocusout: false,
        rules: {
            Age: "required",
            Gender: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            Age: "Please fill in age",
            Gender: "Please fill in gender",
        },
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(errorMap));
        }
    });
}
```

API refernce : https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate