# 'this' inside a template literal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

According to the ES6 spec, the syntax

```
foo`Hello!`
```

should behave exactly like

```
foo('Hello!')
```

> Putting a template literal after an expression triggers a function
>   call, similar to how a parameter list (comma-separated values in
>   parentheses) triggers a function call. The previous code is equivalent
>   to the following function call (in reality, the function gets more
>   information, but that is explained later).

[Source](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_template-literals.html)

However, in the following snippet, binding a value to a function causes the 2 syntaxes to behave differently:

```js
function alertParans() { alert(this)  }
function alertNoParans() { alert `${this}`  }

var executeParans = alertParans.bind('roman empire');
var executeNoParans = alertNoParans.bind('greek empire');

executeParans();
executeNoParans();
```

The first call prints 'roman empire' whilst the second will always just print a comma. Why?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gcbhvqu5/)

Comment: @Claies no, that's exactly what the question is about. He is using `alert` as a tagging function (which it was of course not intended for).

Comment: [Don't use `alert()` for debugging.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203473/why-is-console-log-considered-better-than-alert)

Comment: @Claies - No, the parentheses isn't needed -> https://jsfiddle.net/gcbhvqu5/1/ but in this case they solve the issue, which isn't the lack of parentheses, but using alert as a tag function

Comment: ok I think I understand the dilemma here, sorry to be of confusion.

Comment: And just to be clear, swapping `alert` with `console.log` would show the difference clear as day, which is why you never use `alert` for debugging

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should read the example you linked to, as it says something different than you claim.

[In the section it is stated that the following examples are equivalent](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_template-literals.html#_tagged-template-literals):

```
tagFunction`Hello ${firstName} ${lastName}!`
tagFunction(['Hello ', ' ', '!'], firstName, lastName)
```

Now if you were to apply this to alert, it would look like this:

```
function alertParans() { alert(['', ''], this);  }
function alertNoParans() { alert`${this}`;  }

var executeParans = alertParans.bind('roman empire');
var executeNoParans = alertNoParans.bind('greek empire');

executeParans();
executeNoParans();
```

Now you get the comma in both cases, as the first argument of `alert` is now always an array with two empty strings. Why?

Because template literals are split into the contents before (`''`), during (`this`) and after (`''`) the interpolation.