# How to use getElementsByClassName to get all tags with certain class?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="dropdowntextbox">
        <input type="text" class="dropdowntext">
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Hi again</a>
            <a>Hi again</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdowntextbox">
        <input type="text" class="dropdowntext">
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Hi again</a>
            <a>Hi again</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        alert(document.getElementsByClassName("dropdowntextbox"));
        for (div in document.getElementsByClassName("dropdowntextbox")){
            alert(div.toString());
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The alerts of this code return:

```
[object HTMLCollection]
0
1
length
item
namedItem
```

I expected the alerts to give me `[object HTMLCollection]` and then just the two `<div>` elements that have `class="dropdowntextbox"`. What's the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: just use for (div in document.getElementsByClassName("dropdowntextbox")){
            console.log(div, document.getElementsByClassName("dropdowntextbox")[div]);
        } to see what this output means! your iterating an oject

Comment: Side note: you'll do yourself [a huge favor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203473/why-is-console-log-considered-better-than-alert) if you learn how to use [the console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) for debugging instead of alerts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for..in` iterates properties of a given object. That is, you're iterating `HTMLCollection` properties.

You need to use `Array.from` to convert the whole `HTMLCollection` into a regular array and use `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("dropdowntextbox")).forEach(el => {

})
```

Also, you can use `for..of` if you are in a ES2015+ environment:

```
for(let el of Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("dropdowntextbox"))) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the HTMLCollection is in fact an object, as you can see by logging

```
typeof document.getElementsByClassName("dropdowntextbox");
```

So your *for .. in* cycles through the object keys.
To actually cycle the HTML objects you can convert the HTMLCollection to an array with

```
var nodes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("dropdowntextbox"));
```

and then cycle as usual with

```
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
    //use nodes[i]
}
```

Comment: A `for` loop can handle HTMLCollections. So no need to convert it to an array.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="dropdowntextbox">
        <input type="text" class="dropdowntext">
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Hi again</a>
            <a>Hi again</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdowntextbox">
        <input type="text" class="dropdowntext">
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Hi again</a>
            <a>Hi again</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
  var tags = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdowntextbox");  
        for (var i=0; i < tags.length;i++){
            alert(tags[i].toString());
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You should use below for loop:

`var tags = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdowntextbox");

for (var i=0; i < tags.length;i++){
   alert(tags[i].toString());
}`

Comment: This is what I went with in the end. It's the simplest approach

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `for..in` loop, which iterates over **enumerable property names** of an object - this gives you all the properties of the object, in this case an HTMLCollection (not an array which would give you your expected behaviour)

By using a `for..of` loop instead, it will use the iteration method **specific to the object**, looping over the values generated by the iterator; in this case, your 3 divs.

```
for (let div of document.getElementsByClassName("dropdowntextbox")){
   alert(div.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your "for" loop, you loop through properties of the HTMLCollection object.

You should do something like:

```
var collection = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdowntextbox");

for(x = 0; x < collection.length; x++)
{
  alert(collection[x].innerHtml);
}
```

Test here: [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementsbyclassname)