# Alert an array with while loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

Using while loop, I want to alert names with their number from an array. I also have to put every name in a single alert.

Script:

```
var voetbalteam = 1;

var spelers = ["Nobert Alblas", "Kostas Lamprou", "André Onana", "Benjamin van Leer", "Léon Bergsma", "Damil Dankerlui", "Matthijs de Ligt", "Mitchell Dijks", "Luis Orejuela", "Daley Sinkgraven", "Joël Veltman", "Nick Viergever", "Max Wöber", "Deyovaisio Zeefuik", "Frenkie de Jong", "Siem de Jong", "Carel Eiting", "Noussair Mazaoui", "Lasse Schöne", "Donny van de Beek", "Klaas Jan Huntelaar", "Kasper Dolberg", "Justin Kluivert"];


while ((voetbalteam <= 23) + (spelers >= 0)){
    alert("Ik ben " + spelers[spelers] + " En ik ben de " + voetbalteam + "e speler.");

    spelers ++;

    voetbalteam ++;
}
```

Comment: What part of your script is not working?

Answer (score 3):

Use [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop over the array.

```js
var voetbalteam = 1;

var spelers = ["Nobert Alblas", "Kostas Lamprou", "André Onana", "Benjamin van Leer", "Léon Bergsma", "Damil Dankerlui", "Matthijs de Ligt", "Mitchell Dijks", "Luis Orejuela", "Daley Sinkgraven", "Joël Veltman", "Nick Viergever", "Max Wöber", "Deyovaisio Zeefuik", "Frenkie de Jong", "Siem de Jong", "Carel Eiting", "Noussair Mazaoui", "Lasse Schöne", "Donny van de Beek", "Klaas Jan Huntelaar", "Kasper Dolberg", "Justin Kluivert"];

spelers.forEach(function(key, value){
  console.log("Ik ben " + key + " En ik ben de " + (value + 1) + "e speler.");
});
```

Using a while loop, use `voetbalteam` as an iterator and increment it inside the while loop.

```js
var voetbalteam = 0;

    var spelers = ["Nobert Alblas", "Kostas Lamprou", "André Onana", "Benjamin van Leer", "Léon Bergsma", "Damil Dankerlui", "Matthijs de Ligt", "Mitchell Dijks", "Luis Orejuela", "Daley Sinkgraven", "Joël Veltman", "Nick Viergever", "Max Wöber", "Deyovaisio Zeefuik", "Frenkie de Jong", "Siem de Jong", "Carel Eiting", "Noussair Mazaoui", "Lasse Schöne", "Donny van de Beek", "Klaas Jan Huntelaar", "Kasper Dolberg", "Justin Kluivert"];


    while (voetbalteam < spelers.length){
        console.log("Ik ben " + spelers[voetbalteam] + " En ik ben de " + (voetbalteam + 1) + "e speler.");
        voetbalteam ++;
    }
```

consider using `console.log()` instead of `alert()` when you are coding.

- `alert()` is blocking
- `alert()` cannot be easily suppressed in non-debug environment
- `console` typically formats your objects nicely and allows to traverse
  them
- logging statements often have an interactive pointer to code which
  issued logging statement
- you cannot look at more than one `alert()` message at a time
- `consoles` can have different logging levels with intuitive formatting

[The above text was taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203473/why-is-console-log-considered-better-than-alert/8203493#8203493)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a while loop, try this:

```
var voetbalteam = 0;

var spelers = ["Nobert Alblas", "Kostas Lamprou", "André Onana", "Benjamin van Leer", "Léon Bergsma", "Damil Dankerlui", "Matthijs de Ligt", "Mitchell Dijks", "Luis Orejuela", "Daley Sinkgraven", "Joël Veltman", "Nick Viergever", "Max Wöber", "Deyovaisio Zeefuik", "Frenkie de Jong", "Siem de Jong", "Carel Eiting", "Noussair Mazaoui", "Lasse Schöne", "Donny van de Beek", "Klaas Jan Huntelaar", "Kasper Dolberg", "Justin Kluivert"];

while (voetbalteam < spelers.length){
  alert("Ik ben " + spelers[voetbalteam] + " En ik ben de " + (voetbalteam + 1) + "e speler.");
  voetbalteam++;
}
```