# How to use alert() to show elements of array in JS?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, alert

I wanted to try to print elements of array (animals), so that each one of its elements be in new line (\n). Unfortunately, I couldn't manage to do it. Could someone solve that problem using the logic I have made inside console.log()? And yes, I would like single alert to show given message :)

```js
    let animals = ["fox", "elephant", "wolf"];

    console.log("List of animals:");
    for (let animal of animals) {
        let itemNum = animals.indexOf(animal) + 1;
        console.log(`${itemNum}: ${animal}`);
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
List of animals:
1: fox
2: elephant
3: wolf
```

Can someone think of a solution that would work for alert() as well?

Comment: So whats the problem with your current solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alert an array with while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47952326/alert-an-array-with-while-loop)

Comment: Nothing is wrong with this solution. I would like to have same logic just inside alert() method. How can I do it? And padaleiana nope, it doesn't..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could do it like this:

```
    let animals = ["fox", "elephant", "wolf"];

    let str = "List of animals:\n"
    for (let animal of animals) {
        let itemNum = animals.indexOf(animal) + 1;
        str += `${itemNum}: ${animal}\n`
    }

    alert(str)
```

Comment: Creative :) Thanks mate!

Comment: Or `alert(animals.map((a, i) => \`${i + 1): ${a}\`).join('\n'))` (but consider at least one intermediate const).

Comment: Agreed i was just leaving it similar to how he set it up

Answer (score 0):

better use console.table() if you have an array of objects, dude

something like that:

```
const list = [{name: 'john', age: 10}, {name: 'misha', age: 24},{name: 'aaron', age: 50},]
console.table(Object.values(list))
```