# Retry an AJAX after failure due to internet disconnection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call an ajax request again after the internet failure.

Can anyone help me with this? Here is my code.

```
var loadAgain = function(){
    $.ajax({url: 'URL',
        success: function(result){
            alert('Success');
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (XMLHttpRequest.readyState == 0) {
                alert('No internet connection');
                setTimeout(loadAgain, 500);
            }
            else {
                alert('Other Issue');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Edited**: I have seen another option but I want to recall the ajax on internet disconnect.

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: It's doesn't get called again after failure

Comment: Have you debugged it? Does your setTimeout get called?

Comment: BTW never, ever, ever use `async:false`

Comment: @Liam Yes the setTimeout didn't get called also, I have remove the async:false

Comment: Your checking the [wrong object for the wrong thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543683/determine-if-ajax-error-is-a-timeout)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if $.ajax error is a timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543683/determine-if-ajax-error-is-a-timeout)

Comment: @Liam Not a duplicate. Answer you linked to fails a request early if it exceeds a specific time duration, OP is trying to retry a request after a certain time if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

The only issue is your check of `readyState` when you should actually be checking for a status code. Once a request is fired off, `readyState` will never equal `0`, even if it fails ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState)).

Here's what your code should look like:

```
function loadAgain(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'URL',
        success: function(){
            console.log('Success');
        },
        error: function(event) {
            if (event.statusCode === 0) {
                console.error('No internet connection');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    loadAgain();
                }, 500);
            }
            else {
                // do something else...
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Also, I replaced your alerts with console statements. Get into the habit of using those, they're much easier to debug ([see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8203493/2535504)).

Comment: Status codes are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status) for reference

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya Unnecessary bloating for a simple 1-3 line solution.