# fail to modify content of template

Tags: javascript, html

```
<template id="entry-temp">
    <li id="movie-list">
        <span id="movie-info"> <span id = "li-movie-title"></span> (<span id = "li-movie-year"></span>) - <span id = "li-movie-rating"></span></span>
        <button type="submit" id="movie-edit" name="movie-edit">edit</button>
        <button type="submit" id="movie-delete" name="movie-delete">delete</button>
    </li>
</template>



function appendMovie(title, year, rating) {
    let template = document.querySelector("#entry-temp");
    let tempNode = document.importNode(template.content, true);
    tempNode.querySelector("#li-movie-title").innerHTMl = title;
    tempNode.querySelector("#li-movie-year").innerHTMl = year;
    tempNode.querySelector("#li-movie-rating").innerHTMl = rating;

    let moviePanel = document.getElementById("movie-panel");
    alert(tempNode.innerHTMl);
    moviePanel.appendChild(tempNode);
}
```

The alert gives me undefined, and tempNode is a `document fragment`.

Also, is there a better way to print out the tag in JavaScript for debugging?
For example, How can I check if I really write `title`, `year`, and `rating`?

Comment: Are you sure the `innerHTML` in `alert` statement is not a spelt incorrectly in your original code?

Comment: You can use `console.log` instead of `alert`. It will print into browser's console (Press F12 on Chrome/Firefox, click Console tab and see the outputs print in real time). 

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203473/why-is-console-log-considered-better-than-alert

Comment: hmm good catch..  It's the spelling....  Thanks for y'all time......