# shorter way to check if a title exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

Checking if a `title` already exists. Is there a shorter way? Something like:

```
if(test.exists.inside('.title'){...
```

```js
var x = 0;
var test = $('#test').text();
$('.title').each(function(){
if($(this).text() == test){x = 1;}
});
if(x == 1){console.log('exists');}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>ipsum</div>
<div class='title'>lorema</div>
<div class='title'>ipsuma</div>

<div id='test'>lorem</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered ```document.title```?  ```console.log(document.title)``` Origin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057059/how-to-get-the-title-of-html-page-with-javascript)

Comment: @tomerpacific, no, example pls

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of "shorter"? Code golfing, or what do you think about using a more *appropriate* method if it takes more characters? (note that the jQuery library itself requires *tons* of characters :) )

Comment: @CertainPerformance, `shorter` means `shorter`. less code for such a trivial thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a lot of ways to do this `:contains` , `filter()` with `indexOf()` and `filter()` with `text` equal `test`.. depending on what you're trying to do

```js
var x = 0;
var test = $('#test').text();
var Exists = $('.title:contains("'+test+'")').length;
console.log('Yes '+Exists+ ' title with text '+test);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>ipsum</div>
<div class='title'>lorema</div>
<div class='title'>ipsuma</div>

<div id='test'>lorem</div>
```

you can check also with *for contains text check*

```
$('.title:contains("'+test+'")').length > 0
```

**OR** *for exact text check*

```
$('.title').filter(function(){
  return $(this).text().trim() == test;
}).length > 0
```

> **Note:** `:contains` and `.indexOf` search for the text contains text not the exact text .. by using `$(this).text().trim() == test;` this
>   will return the exact text element

Comment: `:contains` checks whether the text exists *anywhere*, not if an element contains *exactly and only* the text

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes this is what I said in my answer before code .*depending on what you're trying to do*

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for *shorter* code, one option would be to invoke `Array.prototype.some`, and rather than store the result of `.text()` in a variable, invoke it every time, to save on characters typed:

```js
if ([].some.call($('.title'), d => $(d).text() === $('#test').text())) {
  console.log('exists');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>ipsum</div>
<div class='title'>lorema</div>
<div class='title'>ipsuma</div>

<div id='test'>lorem</div>
```

Personally, I'd prefer readability over code length:

```js
const textToFind = $('#test').text();
const exists = Array.prototype.some.call(
  $('.title'),
  title => $(title).text() === textToFind
);
if (exists) {
  console.log('exists');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>ipsum</div>
<div class='title'>lorema</div>
<div class='title'>ipsuma</div>

<div id='test'>lorem</div>
```