# How can I have a drop down box where you pick something and it sets the HTML <title> tag set to what the drop down is set on?

Tags: html, page-title

This is what I have but I don't know how to get it to a variable in JS

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<button onclick="myFunction()">set</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.title;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by `HTML <title> tag set to what the drop down is set on?` ? Do you want it so when you hover over option with `value="1"` that the title object is set to `1` and so on so for down to `option` where `value="4"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code you are storing current title in var x. you need to write like this:

document.title="Some Text or variable";

if you need to set value of dropdown item as title then to give id to select tag then
var newtitle = document.getElementById("id_of_selectTag").value;
document.title=newtitle;

Answer (score 0):

There is already answers on StackOverflow: [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript) and [How to get the title of HTML page with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057059/how-to-get-the-title-of-html-page-with-javascript). You can set title assigning the desired value to `document.title` variable.